# Set umask when mounting USB on Mac

Tags: macos

I have an [Aegis Secure Key](http://www.apricorn.com/products/hardware-encrypted-drives/aegis-secure-key.html) that I want to mount on my Mac with a specific umask (077). On Linux I would just add a line in /etc/fstab:

> /dev/disk/by-id/usb-Apricorn_Secure_Ke /media/SecureKey vfat uid=foo,gid=bar,rw,user,noauto,umask=0077 0 0

This doesn't appear to work on my Mac. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out. First I had to use Disk Utility to figure out the UUID (select the device, then click on info).  Then I just added a line like so to /etc/fstab (using vifs to edit fstab):

> UUID=FEE416CE-8FB7-30DC-B80E-88138D42EAD9 /Users/foo/mounts/key msdos noauto,-m=700